# Hiding one of the divs contained within the header one a single page

Tags: css, css-selectors, hide

I'm trying to find out how to hide a div that's contained within the header.php on a single page of a wordpress site.

In other words, I want to keep the header on this page except for this one div it houses. Ideally I'd like to do this via CSS, but I've been unsuccessful as so far.

The div I'd like to hide is site-description

here's the header.php template code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Header Template
 *
 * The header template is generally used on every page of your site. Nearly all other templates call it 
 * somewhere near the top of the file. It is used mostly as an opening wrapper, which is closed with the 
 * footer.php file. It also executes key functions needed by the theme, child themes, and plugins. 
 *
 * @package Origin
 * @subpackage Template
 */
?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo( 'html_type' ); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

<?php if ( hybrid_get_setting( 'origin_favicon_url' ) ) : ?>
<!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo hybrid_get_setting( 'origin_favicon_url' ); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Title -->
<title><?php hybrid_document_title(); ?></title>

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

<!-- WP Head -->
<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body class="<?php hybrid_body_class(); ?>">

    <?php do_atomic( 'open_body' ); // origin_open_body ?>

    <div id="container">

        <div class="wrap">

            <?php do_atomic( 'before_header' ); // origin_before_header ?>

            <div id="header">

                <?php do_atomic( 'open_header' ); // origin_open_header ?>

                    <div id="branding">

                        <?php origin_site_title(); ?>

                    </div><!-- #branding -->

                    <?php get_template_part( 'menu', 'primary' ); // Loads the menu-primary.php template. ?>

                    <?php hybrid_site_description(); ?>

                    <?php do_atomic( 'header' ); // origin_header ?>

                <?php do_atomic( 'close_header' ); // origin_close_header ?>

            </div><!-- #header -->

            <?php do_atomic( 'after_header' ); // origin_after_header ?>

            <?php do_atomic( 'before_main' ); // origin_before_main ?>

            <div id="main">

                <?php do_atomic( 'open_main' ); // origin_open_main ?>
```

As you can probably guess, it's referenced in the CSS file as #site-description. Page ID I'm trying to hide this on is 2.

Here's what I've tried:

```
body.page-id-2 #site-description { display: none !important; }
```

But it hasn't worked. I'm thinking my mistake is connected to the fact that the site-description div is contained within the header.

I've combed other threads on this but just couldn't glean the right learning, so any help is appreciated.

Rendered HTML of the page in question:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">


<!-- Title -->
<title>About</title>

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://elv8r.com/xmlrpc.php" />

<!-- WP Head -->
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.8.1" />
<meta name="template" content="Origin 0.5.6" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="ELV8R &raquo; Feed" href="http://elv8r.com/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="ELV8R &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://elv8r.com/comments/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://elv8r.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://elv8r.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css'  href='http://elv8r.com/wp-content/themes/origin/style.min.css?ver=0.5.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='origin_fancybox-stylesheet-css'  href='http://elv8r.com/wp-content/themes/origin/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css?ver=1' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-droid-serif-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif&#038;ver=1' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='myStyleSheets-css'  href='http://elv8r.com/wp-content/plugins/supreme-google-webfonts/josh-font-style.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://elv8r.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://elv8r.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://elv8r.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://elv8r.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<link rel='next' title='It&#8217;s entrepreneurship gold' href='http://elv8r.com/' />
<link rel='canonical' href='http://elv8r.com/about/' />
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://elv8r.com/?p=2' />
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-0000000-0']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>

    <style type="text/css">

        /* Font size. */
                    html { font-size: 17px; }

        /* Font family. */
                    body { font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif; }

        /* Link color. */
                    a, a:visited, #footer a:hover, .entry-title a:hover { color: #dd5424; }
            #respond #submit, .button, a.button, .wpcf7-submit, #loginform .button-primary { background-color: #dd5424; }
                a:hover, a:focus { color: #000; }

        /* Custom CSS. */
        #mainsignup { height:110px; width:600px;border-color:000000; border:5px solid; border-radius:15px;} #mainsignup:hover  {             background-color:#DAA520;         } #mainemail { padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;  }  h1.page-title.entry-title {text-align:center;color:#000000;}  #site-description {padding-top:.1cm; padding-bottom:.1cm;  } input { font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }   ::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-weight: bold; text-align: center;   }   :-moz-placeholder { font-weight: bold; text-align: center;   } #footermenu li {display: inline;  padding: 20px;  } #footermenu  {     float: center;  width: 470px  } .page-id-2  .site-description {display: none;}

    </style>    

<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>

</head>

<body class="wordpress ltr en_US parent-theme y2014 m03 d21 h20 friday logged-in admin-bar custom-header singular singular-page singular-page-2 page-template-custom">


    <div id="container">

        <div class="wrap">


            <div id="header">


                    <div id="branding">

                        <div id="site-title">
<a href="http://elv8r.com" title="ELV8R" rel="Home">
<img class="logo" src="http://elv8r.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/cropped-ELLV8R.png" alt="ELV8R" />
</a>
</div>

                    </div><!-- #branding -->


                    <div id="site-description"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></div>    


        <div class="breadcrumb-trail breadcrumbs" itemprop="breadcrumb">
            <span class="trail-browse">Browse:</span> <span class="trail-begin"><a href="http://elv8r.com" title="ELV8R">Home</a></span>
             <span class="sep">&raquo;</span> <span class="trail-end">About</span>
        </div>  
            </div><!-- #header -->



            <div id="main">



    <div id="content">


        <div class="hfeed">




                    <div id="post-2" class="hentry page publish post-1 odd author-admin">

                        <h1 class='page-title entry-title'>About</h1>
                        <div class="entry-content">

                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&#8230;</p>


                        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                        <div class="entry-meta"><span class="edit"><a class="post-edit-link" href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&#038;action=edit" title="Edit Page">Edit</a></span></div>

                    </div><!-- .hentry -->





        </div><!-- .hfeed -->


    </div><!-- #content -->




        </div><!-- #main -->




    <div id="sidebar-subsidiary" class="sidebar">


        <section id="hybrid-nav-menu-2" class="widget nav-menu widget-nav-menu"><div id="footermenu" class="menu-menu-1-container"><ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="http://elv8r.com/blog/">Blog</a></li><li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-18"><a href="http://elv8r.com/about/">About</a></li><li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a title="T &amp; C" href="http://elv8r.com/terms-conditions-and-privacy/">T &#038; C</a></li></ul></div></section>

    </div><!-- #sidebar-subsidiary .aside -->





        <div id="footer">


            <div class="footer-content">

                <p class="copyright">Copyright © 2014 <a class="site-link" href="http://elv8r.com" title="ELV8R" rel="home"><span>ELV8R</span></a></p>

<p class="credit">Powered by <a class="wp-link" href="http://wordpress.org" title="State-of-the-art semantic personal publishing platform"><span>WordPress</span></a> and <a class="theme-link" href="http://alienwp.com/themes/origin/" title="Origin WordPress Theme"><span>Origin</span></a></p>

            </div>


        </div><!-- #footer -->


        </div><!-- .wrap -->

    </div><!-- #container -->


    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://elv8r.com/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=3.8.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://elv8r.com/wp-content/themes/origin/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://elv8r.com/wp-content/themes/origin/js/fitvids/jquery.fitvids.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://elv8r.com/wp-content/themes/origin/js/footer-scripts.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://elv8r.com/wp-content/themes/origin/js/navigation.js?ver=20130228'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://elv8r.com/wp-content/themes/origin/library/js/drop-downs.min.js?ver=20130805'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var request, b = document.body, c = 'className', cs = 'customize-support', rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?'+cs+'(\\s+|$)');

            request = true;

            b[c] = b[c].replace( rcs, ' ' );
            b[c] += ( window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-' ) + cs;
        }());
    </script>
            <div id="wpadminbar" class="nojq nojs" role="navigation">
            <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="#wp-toolbar" tabindex="1">Skip to toolbar</a>
            <div class="quicklinks" id="wp-toolbar" role="navigation" aria-label="Top navigation toolbar." tabindex="0">
                <ul id="wp-admin-bar-root-default" class="ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/about.php" title="About WordPress"><span class="ab-icon"></span></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-about"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/about.php">About WordPress</a>      </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-external" class="ab-sub-secondary ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wporg"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://wordpress.org/">WordPress.org</a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-documentation"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://codex.wordpress.org/">Documentation</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-support-forums"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://wordpress.org/support/">Support Forums</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-feedback"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://wordpress.org/support/forum/requests-and-feedback">Feedback</a>     </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-site-name" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/">ELV8R</a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-site-name-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-dashboard"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a>     </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-appearance" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-themes"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/themes.php">Themes</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-customize" class="hide-if-no-customize"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/customize.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Felv8r.com%2Fabout%2F">Customize</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-widgets"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/widgets.php">Widgets</a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-menus"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php">Menus</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-background"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/themes.php?page=custom-background">Background</a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-header"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/themes.php?page=custom-header">Header</a>      </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-updates"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/update-core.php" title="1 Plugin Update, 1 Theme Update"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">2</span><span class="screen-reader-text">1 Plugin Update, 1 Theme Update</span></a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-comments"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php" title="0 comments awaiting moderation"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span id="ab-awaiting-mod" class="ab-label awaiting-mod pending-count count-0">0</span></a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-content" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/post-new.php" title="Add New"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">New</span></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-new-content-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-post"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/post-new.php">Post</a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-media"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/media-new.php">Media</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-link"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/link-add.php">Link</a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-page"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page">Page</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-user"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/user-new.php">User</a>       </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&#038;action=edit">Edit Page</a>      </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-top-secondary" class="ab-top-secondary ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-search" class="admin-bar-search"><div class="ab-item ab-empty-item" tabindex="-1"><form action="http://elv8r.com/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch"><input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" /><input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search"/></form></div>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-my-account" class="menupop with-avatar"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/profile.php" title="My Account">Howdy, admin<img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/69ba973f89ab176694bdb0a1e59236e6?s=26&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D26&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-26 photo' height='26' width='26' /></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-user-actions" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-user-info"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="-1" href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/profile.php"><img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/69ba973f89ab176694bdb0a1e59236e6?s=64&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D64&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-64 photo' height='64' width='64' /><span class='display-name'>admin</span><span class='username'>rohan</span></a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit-profile"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-admin/profile.php">Edit My Profile</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-logout"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://elv8r.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=c787bd7905">Log Out</a>        </li></ul></div>        </li></ul>          </div>
                        <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="http://elv8r.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=c787bd7905">Log Out</a>
                    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us the rendered html instead of your PHP please.

Comment: Sure thing - rendered HTML added to OP

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to try and replicate yours, it is a simple css class for the div you want to hide

css:

```
.hide {
display: none;
}
```

and add that "hide" class to whatever div you want to hide (You can use id if you want)

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUxXf/2/)

Comment: Thanks - do you know how you would apply that to just one page, based on page ID?

Comment: I never did really work on php. But if you have access to your pageid when rendering your #site-description div, you could append your pageid to the div's id (Example: #site-description2) , which you could hide using #site-description2 specifically from css. That way, #site-description1 won't be hidden.